# MySQL - Where Or?

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I have a MySQL statement where I'm trying to exclude statements depending on where they "belong to" The query goes through, but it still shows the rows that I specifically said where its not equal to?

```
SELECT id, belongsto, title, madeby, sticky, locked, lastpost, posts
FROM threads
WHERE sticky !=1
AND belongsto !=12 OR sticky !=1 AND belongsto !=13
ORDER BY  `threads`.`date` DESC 
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: You don't really need `OR` at all since you're repeating the same criteria of `sticky !=1` on both.

Comment: Removing " `OR sticky !=1`" from the query would be sufficient to fix the issue. The `OR` condition is making it so that a value of 12 will satisfy one side, and a value of 13 will satisfy the other side, so those values don't get "excluded".

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need parenthesis around your `OR` statements to group them together logically.

```
WHERE sticky !=1
AND belongsto !=12 OR sticky !=1 AND belongsto !=13
```

should be:

```
WHERE (sticky !=1 AND belongsto !=12)
OR (sticky !=1 AND belongsto !=13)
```

or better yet:

```
 WHERE sticky !=1 AND belongsto NOT IN(12,13)
```

Comment: belongsto NOT IN(12,13,14), that is plain awesome :) Thanks. Works perfect.

Comment: No parenthesis are "needed". The `AND` operator has a higher precedence than the `OR` operator; the addition of parenthesis (as shown under "should be:") does not change the statement; this does not resolve the issue. The rewrite under "better yet" does change the statement.

Answer (score 3):

If the goal is to exclude rows with belongsto values of `12` and `13`, then the **`OR`** should be replaced with **`AND`**.

The assertion (in the selected answer) that parentheses are "missing" and need to be added, is wrong. The addition of parentheses does not change the change the statement. The `AND` operator already has a higher precedence than the `OR` operator.)

```
WHERE sticky !=1
AND belongsto !=12 AND sticky !=1 AND belongsto !=13
                   ^^^
```

Because it's unnecessary to repeat the same predicate twice, this could be rewritten as:

```
WHERE sticky !=1
AND belongsto !=12 AND belongsto !=13
```

Which can also be written as:

```
WHERE sticky !=1
  AND NOT (belongsto =12 OR belongsto =13)
```

This can also be rewritten using a `NOT IN (12,13)` (as demonstrated in the selected answer).